# Reflection and private delegate fields of events in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, events, reflection, delegates

I'm probably doing something silly, but here it goes.

I'm trying to get the FieldInfo from a public event via reflection.

Check this function:

```
  public void PlotAllFields(Type type) {
      BindingFlags all = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
      FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(all);
      Console.WriteLine(type + "-------------------------");
      foreach (var fieldInfo in fields) {
          Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.Name);
      }
  }

  public class Bar : Foo {}

  public class Foo {
      public string Test;
      public event EventHandler Event;
      public event RoutedEventHandler RoutedEvent;
  }
```

The call PlotAllFields(typeof(Foo)); returns:

- Test
- Event
- RoutedEvent

The call PlotAllFields(typeof(Bar)); returns:

- Test

I understand that the delegates behind the events are private fields
so I can't access them on the subclass. So far so good.

Then I tried: PlotAllFields(typeof(FrameworkElement)); //from WPF

- _themeStyleCache
- _styleCache
- _templatedParent
- _templateChild
- _flags
- _flags2
- _parent
- _inheritableProperties
- MeasureRequest
- ArrangeRequest
- sizeChangedInfo
- _parentIndex
- _parent
- _proxy
- _contextStorage

**Well... Where are the 14 events of FrameworkElement class???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FrameworkElement doesn't use field-like events, it makes calls to [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899.aspx) and [RemoveHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.removehandler.aspx).  Most of the time they don't have handlers attached, so WPF uses a system that is more space-efficient.  For example, here is the Loaded event, from Reflector:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler Loaded
{
    add
    {
        base.AddHandler(LoadedEvent, value, false);
    }
    remove
    {
        base.RemoveHandler(LoadedEvent, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my suspicion, wanted to check, but beaten :)

Comment: Amazing, 3 minutes for the answer. I love Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

try these binding flags

```
BindingFlags.Default |
BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
BindingFlags.Instance |
BindingFlags.NonPublic |
BindingFlags.Public
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.REFLECTION.BINDINGFLAGS);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV3.5%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true