# How to raise Onload/OnUnload event from FrameworkElement for unit testing purposes?

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, events, reflection, delegates

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618085/reflection-and-private-delegate-fields-of-events-in-c), I can't use reflection to get the multicast delegates of the private fields behind these FrameworkElement events because they aren't field-like. So how to do it?

Comment: In your original question, if you can get the routed events for FrameworkElement.Loaded and FrameworkElement.Unloaded, wouldn't that be enough?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try this:

`yourControl.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent));`

It should work! :)